# How do I gain access to these programs?

Tags: permissions, files

```
sharon@sharon:~$ cd /opt/Symantec/symantec_antivirus

sharon@sharon:/opt/Symantec/symantec_antivirus$ ./rtvscand -k shutdown

no permission to access rtvscand

sharon@sharon:/opt/Symantec/symantec_antivirus$ ./symcfgd -k shutdown

no permission to access symcfgd

sharon@sharon:/opt/Symantec/symantec_antivirus$
```

Could someone provide detailed instructions as to how to gain access to the 2 programs?

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu and running version 12.10, 64bit, US English.

Comment: You must put `sudo` previously to the command. e.g.: `sudo ./rtvscand -k shutdown`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried running your command with sudo ? Like

```
sudo ./rtvscand -k shutdown
```

sudo lets you run your command as a user (root) with the permissions todo that.

Comment: @ a2r: Thanks for the tip. Here's the output of sudo-ing the 2 programs: sharon@sharon:~$ cd /opt/Symantec/symantec_antivirus
sharon@sharon:/opt/Symantec/symantec_antivirus$ sudo ./rtvscand -k shutdown
[sudo] password for sharon: 
sharon@sharon:/opt/Symantec/symantec_antivirus$ sudo ./symcfgd -k shutdown
sharon@sharon:/opt/Symantec/symantec_antivirus$

Comment: @n00b Your output is correct, at least for the point of view of the command. So, this answer is correct

Comment: @ Lucio: Thanks pal. Merry Christmas to you and your loved ones.

Comment: Well I don't know the programm but it looks like an antivirus tool (cpt. obvious). 
May I ask what you wanted to do?

Comment: @ a2r: I have been trying to install Symantec Antivirus for Linux on my computer for the past 3 days now. I enjoy learning how to use Linux and Ubuntu this way. It's what I call practice-based learning.

Comment: Well,... I don't want to convince you of something. And I don't want to pretend that a virus on linux is impossible, but you can research a little on google about why linux is a little bit saver then windows.